# Problem with JoinTable relationship with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a JoinTable in Ruby. In my app I have a entity called Professional, and another called ProfessionalAttribute.

Each Professional has a value to a ProfessionalAttribute. Im trying to make it trough a ProfessionalAttributesProfessionals model.

Those are my migrations:

```
class CreateProfessionalAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :professional_attributes do |t|
      t.belongs_to :professional_type
      t.string :title
      t.boolean :show_on_sign_up
      t.boolean :show_on_edit_profile
      t.boolean :searchable
    end
  end
end

class CreateProfessional < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :professionals do |t|
      t.belongs_to :professional_type
      t.belongs_to :user
    end
  end
end

class CreateJoinTableProfessionalAttributes < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_join_table :professionals, :professional_attributes do |t|
      t.index [:professional_id, :professional_attribute_id], {:name => "professional_attributes_index"}
      t.string :value
    end
  end
end
```

And here are my models:

```
class Professional < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :professional_type
  has_many :professional_attributes_professionals
end

class ProfessionalAttributesProfessionals < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :professional
  belongs_to :professional_attributes
end
```

When I run my console, If I create a ProfessionalAttributesProfessionals.new for instance, everything works well.

But when I create a new Professional, and try to retrieve the professional_attributes_professionals I get an error:

```
p = Professional.new
 => #<Professional id: nil, professional_type_id: nil, user_id: nil> 


 > p.professional_attributes_professionals
Traceback (most recent call last):
    2: from (irb):9
    1: from (irb):9:in `rescue in irb_binding'
NameError (uninitialized constant Professional::ProfessionalAttributesProfessional)
```

I dont know what Im doing wrong here. If is something related with pluralize strategy with Rails. But now this is driving me crazy and I tried everything.

Someone can bring me light on it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well. I just found that I need to change the class name from professional_attributes_professionals.rb to professional_attributes_professional.rb and it works.